# Get PropertyChanged notification from one ViewModel to another

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I'm working on my first WPF project.
My UI needs to be more interactive. I've got 2 ViewModels. MainWindowViewModel and WorldViewModel.

MainWindow xaml simplified code:

```
<Window>
    [...]
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <!--Worlds combobox-->
        <ComboBox Margin="2 0 0 0" MinWidth="100" IsEnabled="{Binding IsWorldsComboEnabled}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding WorldViewModel.Worlds}" SelectedValue="{Binding WorldViewModel.CurrentWorld}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs code:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public WorldViewModel WorldViewModel { get; set; }

    public bool IsWorldsComboEnabled => WorldViewModel.Worlds != null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        WorldViewModel = WorldViewModel.Instance;
    }
}
```

WorldViewModel.cs code:

```
public class WorldViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<World> Worlds { get; set; }

    public World CurrentWorld { get; set; }

    public static WorldViewModel Instance { get; set; }

    // Called on startup
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Instance = new WorldViewModel();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public WorldViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

ViewModels are a bit bigger, but that's minimum needed code. `BaseViewModel` is a class which delivers NotifyPropertyChanged Interface with `PropertyChanged.Fody` NuGet package.

My `ComboBox` must be disabled when `Worlds` ObservableCollection is null. It works well when `IsWorldsComboEnabled` is located in `WorldViewModel`, but I feel that it's not a way to go. Multiple views will depend on `WorldViewModel` but they will not need `IsWorldsComboEnabled` property. So it's place is in `MainWindowViewModel`.

Is there any way to notify `MainWindowViewModel` when property in `WorldViewModel` has changed?

Comment: *It works well when IsWorldsComboEnabled is located in WorldViewModel, but I feel that it's not a way to go.* so binding `WorldViewModel.IsWorldsComboEnabled` is not a way to go  but you feel that binding `WorldViewModel.Worlds` is a way ... that's odd ... every `ViewModel` should have its own `View` ...

Comment: `MainWindowViewModel` has the View logic. `WorldViewModel` will not contain any logic for views, as multiple views can depend on this ViewModel. I'm binding `MainWindowViewModel.IsWorldsComboEnabled` to be correct. You've probably missunderstood me. `IsWorldsComboEnabled` depends on `WorldViewModel.Worlds`, but it's place is in `MainWindowViewModel`.

Comment: you prolly missunderstood MVVM again every ViewModel should have its View (unless are abstract and would be extended)

Comment: *IsWorldsComboEnabled depends on WorldViewModel.Worlds, but it's place is in MainWindowViewModel* then MainWindowViewModel is also the place where  Worlds should be ... move Worlds and other stuff to MainViewModel

Comment: What if multiple views will need to operate on the same instance of objects collection. Where to store a data then?

Comment: they are objects(collections) ... you can store multiple referenece in different objects (ViewModels) to the same instance of collection ... but anyway you should rather load it independently from some repository service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the following line of code is that the setter of `IsWorldsComboEnabled` will never be executed even when `WorldViewModel.Worlds` changed, thus your `PropertyChangedEventHandler` will not be called.

```
public bool IsWorldsComboEnabled => WorldViewModel.Worlds != null
```

You might change to `public bool IsWorldsComboEnabled { get; set; }`
and evaluate the following expression

```
IsWorldsComboEnabled = WorldViewModel.Worlds != null;
```

whenever you change the property WorldViewModel.Worlds.

In your case, where the property is a `ObservableCollection`, you might register to the CollectionChanged Event

```
WorldViewModel.Worlds.CollectionChanged += MyCollectionChangedMethod;
```

and evaluate the expression there

```
private void MyCollectionChangedMethod(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  IsWorldsComboEnabled = WorldViewModel.Worlds != null;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. That is exactly what I need! Thank You so much! ☺